# Integrability of $\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

I was reading the paper

> Quelques remarques sur les problemes elliptiques quasilineaires du
> second ordre, P. L. Lions, Journal d’Analyse Mathématique volume 45,
> pages 234–254(1985)

and on page 250 he claims that the distance function $d(x) = \mathrm{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$ satisfies
$$ \int_\Omega d(x)^{-\theta}\;dx < \infty$$
for all $\theta \in (0,1)$.

Here $\Omega$ is a nice open, bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am not sure how to prove this result. We can assume $\partial \Omega$ is $C^2$ (not sure if we need a convex domain or not).

Here is an attempt, we only need to show this near the boundary, say $0<d(x)<\delta$.
$$ \int_{0<d(x)<\delta} d(x)^{-\theta}\;dx  = \int_{\partial \Omega} \int_0^\delta\left(\frac{1}{s^\theta}ds\right)d\xi$$
since every point in this region is given by $x = x_0 - s \vec{n}$ as long as $d(x) = s$, where $\vec{n}$ is the outward normal vector at $x_0$, the projection of $x$ onto $\partial \Omega$, i.e.,
$$ d(x) = |x-x_0|.$$
Now
$$ \int_{0<d(x)<\delta} d(x)^{-\theta}\;dx  = \int_{\partial \Omega} \int_0^\delta\left(\frac{1}{s^\theta}ds\right)d\xi = \int_{\partial \Omega}\left(\frac{\delta^{1-\theta}}{1-\theta}\right) d\xi < \infty\quad \text{if}\quad \Omega\;\text{is bounded.}$$

Comment: Where does $\Omega$ lives, and what is your question ?

Comment: Is $x$ in the interior of $\Omega$ ?

Comment: Have you tried elementary cases ($\Omega$=sphere, cube) in $\mathbb{R^2}$ for example ?

Comment: No answer to our questions... Do you know that dialog can help to build solutions ?

Comment: Hi, I am thinking about it, I guess one can write the integral near the boundary as integration over the boundary within another layer of integration from 0 to some small $\delta$, and showing that integral is finite.

Comment: For a sphere it is obvious, you are right.

Comment: Is the above answer correct?

Comment: Your development (I was unaware of it) looks correct and indeed uses the fact that $\theta \in (0,1)$ . Besides, I just understood a little better the context by seeing your MathOverflow question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/377525)

Comment: Thank you very much!